# before/after route method with Marionette AppRouter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

In Backbone Router there is a chance to use before/after methods to define what's going to happen before/after the route get fired.

I'm using [Marionette AppRouter](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.approuter.html) and I discover I cannot do the same with it.

Do you know any way to reproduce the same behavior with AppRouter? I was thinking maybe there is a extension to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful to see what your method for doing this with Backbone is and what you have tried with Marionette that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`Marionette.AppRouter` extends `Backbone.Router`, so if you have a way to execute callbacks before and after a routing event with `Backbone.Router` you should be able to do the same thing with `Marionette.Router`.